# Why JS bind "fails"(?) like that?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

```
["ab", "bc"].filter((x) => "bc".includes(x))
```

Result: `[ "bc" ]`
But:

```
["ab", "bc"].filter("".includes.bind("bc"))
```

Results: `[]`
And that is a mystery I do not understand, and to further mystify:

```
["bc"].filter("".includes.bind("bc"))
```

Is `[ "bc" ]`

Would appreciate someone explaining, I would almost think it is a bug... But both FF and Chromium act same.

Comment: I would build a curried function `const includes = a => b => a.includes(b)` and partially apply it as follow: `xs.filter(includes("bc"))`. Does the same job than what you're trying to do with `Function#bind` but with less ambiguity IMHO (of course YMMV).

Comment: @customcommander an alternative is to create a function that sets the arity of another, so you'd call something like `ary(1, "".includes.bind("bc"))` (or `ary(1)("".includes.bind("bc"))` if it's curried. Maybe even `unary("".includes.bind("bc")`). That's assuming you have an function for arity already. Probably not worth making/getting one just for this case and a curried `includes` is a simpler approach.

Comment: Well first version is shorter than such stuff. It is a bit sad that there is no normal filter function :) But I guess that's js for you, not real functional language, just with decent support. Arity thing is nice if such stuff is needed for more than on off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`String.prototype.includes`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) accepts *two* arguments: `searchString`, and `position`.
[`Array.prototype.filter`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) will pass *three* arguments into the callback: `currentValue`, **`index`**, and `array`.

`''.includes.bind('bc')('bc', 1)` is `false`.